# Unity - TMP Input Field : How to limit number of digits after decimal point in Decimal Type

Tags: unity-game-engine, input-field, unity-ui

Is there any easy way to limit the number of digits after the decimal point with an TMP_InputField set at decimal type ?

For exemple, if the user type 12.347, I want the text to stop at 12.34

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: If anyone else is looking for the exact same thing as me, I succeeded by doing this little trick :

```
        if (_hasComa)
        {
            string[] charAfterComa = _inputField.text.Split(",");
            string strAfterComa = charAfterComa[1];

            for (int i = 0; i < strAfterComa.Length; i++)
            {
                if (i >= 2)
                {
                    int index = strAfterComa.LastIndexOf(strAfterComa[i]);
                    if (index >= 0)
                        strAfterComa = strAfterComa.Substring(0, index);
                }
            }

            _inputField.text = charAfterComa[0] + ',' + strAfterComa;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register to an event `onValidateInput`, parse the string to a float, and reformat it with `$"{value:0.##}`.

Comment: Thanks !! I will try this when I am at home. But it will change only when I will enter or leave the field, so I guess it’s impossible to limit it “in live” while the user is typing ?

Answer (score 0):

[You got an option in the text mesh pro input field for limiting the characters that players enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHTUn.png)